# How can I access Tonilia after the final quest without the Thieves' Guild armor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

Okay. I don't give a skeever tail about *having* the item, but I do care about finishing the quest.

I hadn't bothered to do the Thieves' Guild quests for quite a while after initially joining (and promptly selling the armor) back at the 30 hours of gameplay mark. At about 160 hours of gameplay I went back to go finish up the thieves guild quests and wrap up gathering the very last of the stones. After all that work and all that collecting, the armor I sold about 110 play hours earlier is stopping me from completing my last achievement.

Is there any workaround that works on the Xbox 360 and does **not** involve going back 100+ gameplay hours?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, without access to the console for the PC, there is still no way of getting around this.  You will have to wait for a patch.

Comment: Oh thank the stars- if it's already in patch notes- I'll just set aside the game till after Christmas and finish it up after the patch adds a dialog option for her. I do have a few other games that were waiting till I'd Skyrim'd out.

Comment: @Meryddin sorry, bad wording on my part there.  What I meant is you'll have to wait and see if they patch it in the next patch.  I don't think they've mentioned for sure that they will, and even if they did I'm not sure if they'll just fix it for new playthroughs and not current ones.

Comment: Oh for... I think I may just set it aside and hope for a patch anyways. Thanks a bunch for the clarification! (in a few weeks this plan will likely change to researching power leveling a pure thief just to finish out that quest line but for now...)

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, there is no way to acquire Tonalia as a fence nor complete the final quest without the armor. I wish there was something more constructive or helpful I could say, but that's the harsh truth.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is Thieves Guild armour spread around near the beds - I had this same predicament but found a pair of gloves on the floor next to a bed. This enabled me to finish Tonila's part of the game and open her up as a fence.

Comment: Are you sure this is the case on the xbox version?